# android Prevent a background app from launching activities in the foreground

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity in my application that does a process and when finished, launches an activity with a normal intent:

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent();
intent2.setClass(anActivity.this, JustAnotherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent2);
finish();
```

The problem is that when you are doing the process, if I press the home button and take it to the background, when it finishes and calls the new activity, even if it is in the home of the phone, this new activity jumps to the foreground.

I am looking for the activity to be launched, but if the user is outside the application, it does not come to the foreground.

I guess the use of a FLAG is necessary, but the ones I have tried have not worked.

sorry for my bad english

Thanks.

Comment: uhmmm, but you would know how to solve my problem?

Comment: the process I'm doing requires graphic views, so I can not do it from a service. I think you have not understood what I'm looking for.

Comment: acctually I didn't ... well, it is not possible ... also it doesn't make sens ... in meantime the activity(or rather even your whole process) may be killed ... use foreground service for processing .. if processing is finished either show next activity or launch notification depends on application state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you take care of ActivityLifecycle (OnPause, OnStop).

You can add a flag when the activity goes "OnPause/OnStop" depending what you want. And them perform the intent just if the activity is not "Pause/Stop".

[Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)